# How can I wait for the create/edit entity modal window to finish rendering and execute my custom js code in 2sxc module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

When user presses either create entity button or edit entity button, there's the same modal window in an iframe that is build by js dynamically. So what I'm trying to do is to wait until it's fully rendered and then execute my custom js code. So is there a proper way to do that? Some sort of event like `RenderFinished` shooting or something? Don't want to use timeout since I understand that it's not a good way to do that.
What I tried so far is that I've added jquery to the page programmatically, since it's not used currently at that particular page for some reason (probably because iframe is built dynamically without jquery and I needed to add it myself).
After that I tried to access iframe via jquery selector and then on iframe.ready access element inside in the same manner (selector and even ready for that element). But iframe is accessed and element inside it is not. Console log inside ready function just outputs no elements found. When I placed breakpoint inside I saw that there's no modal window built yet and my code is executed synchronously before it. So there's nothing to find yet at that moment.
Oh and I tried to put it all inside `$(document).ready`, of course. But it didn't change the situation neither...
Any ideas about how to do that properly?

The final goal why am I doing all this complicated dancing: I'm trying to add validation that UrlKey for entity is unique. So I want to bind my js function to UrlKey input's `onchange` event and call backend api to do the validation and return new UrlKey if it wasn't unique and edit the UrlKey input accordingly. The problem that I stumbled upon is to execute my code after modal iframe window is rendered.
Any tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck :)

2sxc added a Formula feature which will help you with this. There are videos and tutorials and more. See http://r.2sxc.org/formulas